# Opencart session info in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, integration, opencart

I have a site that is using both WordPress and Opencart. The main site is built off of WP and then there is an OC site in a sub-directory.

I would like to bring the session data from OC into the wordpress site so I can have the Wishlist, Shopping Cart, Checkout, Login status and My Account info throughout the site.

Does anyone know what code I can add to WP to bring in this info?

Thanks again in advance,

Matt

Comment: What is your folder and URL structure? Example, site.com/wp, site.com/wp/oc - if so, you can call the relevant global opencart headers to include the opencart sessions and then you can simply spit out via the relevant objects nice and clean.

Comment: That sounds great but my question is how can I do that? I am not familiar with how to call the OC session data. 

My structure is site.com/ (wordpress) and site.com/products (opencart).

I have the opencart header info in my code but need to add something to bring in variables. For Example:

'<?php  if (!$logged): ?>
<li class="inline"><a href=""> Log In</a> or <a href="" title="Create an account">create an account</a>.
</li>
<?php  else: ?>
<li class="inline">You are logged in as <?php echo $first_name; ?>(<a href=""> Log Out</a>)
<a href="">My  Account</a>
</li>
<?php   endif; ?>'

Answer (score 1):

There are already many articles regarding module development and export and session building in OpenCart.

Given your existing pages:

```
yoursite.com/wordpress
yoursite.com/wordpress/page.php (i.e. your page outside the shop),
yoursite.com/products/catalog/controller/common/header.php -and-
yoursite/products/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl
```

## 1. Create file headerXYZ.php using the following code and save it to the root directory of your main site (or other location of your choosing outside your OC shop).

```
<?php
// Config
require_once('shop/config.php');

// VirtualQMOD
require_once('shop/vqmod/vqmod.php');
$vqmod = new VQMod();

// VQMODDED Startup
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php'));

// Application Classes
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/customer.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/affiliate.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/currency.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/tax.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/weight.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/length.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/cart.php'));

$myVar = array();

$myVar = array();

// Registry
$registry = new Registry();

// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);

// Config
$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);

// Database
$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$registry->set('db', $db);

// Url
$url = new Url($config->get('config_url'), $config->get('config_use_ssl') ? $config->get('config_ssl') :

$config->get('config_url'));   
$registry->set('url', $url);

// Log
$log = new Log($config->get('config_error_filename'));
$registry->set('log', $log);

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
   global $log, $config;

   switch ($errno) {
      case E_NOTICE:
      case E_USER_NOTICE:
         $error = 'Notice';
         break;
      case E_WARNING:
      case E_USER_WARNING:
         $error = 'Warning';
         break;
      case E_ERROR:
      case E_USER_ERROR:
         $error = 'Fatal Error';
         break;
      default:
         $error = 'Unknown';
         break;
   }

   if ($config->get('config_error_display')) {
      echo '<b>' . $error . '</b>: ' . $errstr . ' in <b>' . $errfile . '</b> on line <b>' . $errline . '</b>';
   }

   if ($config->get('config_error_log')) {
      $log->write('PHP ' . $error . ':  ' . $errstr . ' in ' . $errfile . ' on line ' . $errline);
   }

   return true;
}

// Error Handler
set_error_handler('error_handler');

// Request
$request = new Request();
$registry->set('request', $request);

// Response
$response = new Response();
$response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$response->setCompression($config->get('config_compression'));
$registry->set('response', $response);

// Cache
$cache = new Cache();
$registry->set('cache', $cache);

// Session
$session = new Session();
$registry->set('session', $session);

// Language Detection
$languages = array();

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "language");

foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
   $languages[$result['code']] = $result;
}

$detect = '';

if (isset($request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) && ($request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
   $browser_languages = explode(',', $request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

   foreach ($browser_languages as $browser_language) {
      foreach ($languages as $key => $value) {
         if ($value['status']) {
            $locale = explode(',', $value['locale']);

            if (in_array($browser_language, $locale)) {
               $detect = $key;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

if (isset($request->get['language']) && array_key_exists($request->get['language'], $languages) &&

$languages[$request->get['language']]['status']) {
   $code = $request->get['language'];
} elseif (isset($session->data['language']) && array_key_exists($session->data['language'], $languages)) {
   $code = $session->data['language'];
} elseif (isset($request->cookie['language']) && array_key_exists($request->cookie['language'], $languages)) {
   $code = $request->cookie['language'];
} elseif ($detect) {
   $code = $detect;
} else {
   $code = $config->get('config_language');
}

if (!isset($session->data['language']) || $session->data['language'] != $code) {
   $session->data['language'] = $code;
}

if (!isset($request->cookie['language']) || $request->cookie['language'] != $code) {    
   setcookie('language', $code, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/', $request->server['HTTP_HOST']);
}         

$config->set('config_language_id', $languages[$code]['language_id']);
$config->set('config_language', $languages[$code]['code']);

// Language   
$language = new Language($languages[$code]['directory']);
$language->load($languages[$code]['filename']);   
$registry->set('language', $language);

// Document
$document = new Document();
$registry->set('document', $document);       

// Customer
$registry->set('customer', new Customer($registry));

// Affiliate
$affiliate = new Affiliate($registry);      
$registry->set('affiliate', $affiliate);

if (isset($request->get['tracking']) && !isset($request->cookie['tracking'])) {
   setcookie('tracking', $request->get['tracking'], time() + 3600 * 24 * 1000, '/');
}

// Currency
$registry->set('currency', new Currency($registry));

// Tax
$tax = new Tax($registry);
$registry->set('tax', $tax);

// Weight
$registry->set('weight', new Weight($registry));

// Length
$registry->set('length', new Length($registry));

// Cart
$registry->set('cart', new Cart($registry));

// Front Controller
$controller = new Front($registry);

// Maintenance Mode
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/maintenance'));

// SEO URL's
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/seo_url'));

// Router
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
   $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
   $action = new Action('common/home');
}

// Dispatch
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));
```

## 2. Now, include headerXYZ.php in page.php i.e. Place the statement below on line 1 at the very top of page.php

```
<?php require_once ('headerXYZ.php');?>
```

## 3. Finally, right after the opening body tag of your external page.php page add the following list of statements

```
<?php
require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/sub_total.php');
require_once('shop/catalog/language/english/total/sub_total.php');
require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/reward.php');
require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/shipping.php');
require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/coupon.php');
require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/tax.php');
require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/credit.php');
require_once('shop/catalog/language/english/total/credit.php');
require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/voucher.php');
require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/total.php');
require_once('shop/catalog/language/english/total/total.php');
foreach($myVar as $key=>$value)
{
   $$key = $value;
}

require_once('shop/catalog/controller/common/header.php');
require_once('shop/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl');
?>
```

That's it... You're done! You should now have a fully functional header (with working cart, login, etc.) in your page located outside of your Opencart shop.

SIDE NOTE: You could also just plug the entire code (including the content of headerXYZ.php and the 13 require_once statements) directly into the your external page.

Comment: I've not actually been able to the code you have posted myself. I am getting a lot of undefined variable errors. Would it be possible to extend/update your example code further?

Comment: I've actually managed to get it working, however it is showing up as a blank page at the moment.

Comment: The code is as exactly as what you have posted above, only that I had to copy over the config.php to reside next to the index.php (which contains the above code you have posted) inside my WordPress theme folder to get rid of the errors.

`require_once('shop/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl');` doesn't actually include the header. I changed it over to use include(...) which now displays the actual header, however it is not including any page information (i.e. `<Title></Title>`).

Comment: It would be best to post in the OpenCart forum and mod support and then once you finally fix the solution post back here. I would also look at turning on PHP errors and debug on so you can see the issues and what errors are happening

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar, what I did was to write same html/css for footer and header in both systems, after that, I wrote an additional Wordpress plugin to show user and cart info when user is logged in opencart.

https://github.com/saRca/op2wp